# Dart/Flutter: How can i calculate values of multiple maps which contains same key?

Tags: flutter, date, dart, maps

I am new to Dart and i got stuck at this point for days.

I have multiple maps and these maps follow the same pattern (date:value) but their lengths are different. And these maps are increased dynamically.

For example:

```
Map1:{01.01.2021:2,02.01.2021:5,03.01.2021:3}, 
Map2:{02.01.2021:10,03.01.2021:4,04.01.2021:8}, 
Map3...
Map4...
...
```

I want to combine these maps and sum the values that contains the same key and store it in an another map. For the different keys, there will be no calculation and store as it is.

Result for Map1 & Map2:

```
Combined Map{01.01.2021:2,02.01.2021:(5+3),03.01.2021:(3+4),04.01.2021:8}
```

How can i perform such an operation considering that these maps are iterable inside a class or inside an another list.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! Paste this on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?)

This will work with any number of maps inside `data` map

Any questions fell free to ask me in the comments.

```
void main() {
  
  final data = {
    'Map1': {'01.01.2021':2,'02.01.2021':5,'03.01.2021':3}, 
    'Map2': {'02.01.2021':10,'03.01.2021':4,'04.01.2021':8}, 
  };

  final finalData = {};
  
  for(final key in data.keys) {
    for(final date in data[key]!.keys) {
      final initialValue = finalData[date];
      
      if(initialValue == null) {
        finalData[date] = data[key]![date];
      } else {
        finalData[date] = initialValue + data[key]![date];
      }
    }
  }
  // {01.01.2021: 2, 02.01.2021: 15, 03.01.2021: 7, 04.01.2021: 8}
  print(finalData);
}
```

The inner loop can be written more succinctly using the tertiary operator

```
for (final date in data[key]!.keys) {
  final initialValue = finalData[date];
  finalData[date] = initialValue == null
      ? data[key]![date]
      : initialValue + data[key]![date];
}
```

or the null aware operator (??)

```
for (final date in data[key]!.keys) {
  finalData[date] = data[key]![date]! + (finalData[date] ?? 0);
}
```

Comment: Consider rewriting using `putIfAbsent` to make it more readable https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html

Comment: Thanks ill give a try, I thought about `putIfAbsent` but didn't solved the sum part for me

Comment: @pedropimont, it worked thank you so much :) . Actually i have two questions on that...

Comment: @pedropimont First of all, how can i put these maps (Map1,Map2.....) to the "data" dynamically that you did manually?

Second question is that, actually what i am trying to do is to use these values in a graph. To do that, instead of summing the values as I mentioned in the previous question, i need to calculate the percentages. During the iteration that you specified, i need to make the calculation below;
for each date;
((Map1Amount*Map1[date])+(Map2Amount*Map2[date]))*100/(Map1Amount+Map2Amount). For the different keys, again there will be no calculation and store as it is.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: @nextlevel as for the percentages I'll try to answer once I get home ony computer

Comment: Thank you. You have put the Map1 and Map2 to a new Map called Data. The question is how can i add these Map1 and Map2 inside the "data" automatically. I am trying and i couldn't succeed yet but i think i will solve it with "map.fromiterable".